# debootstrap creates blank fstab ("UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM") - how do i configure fstab for the first time?

Tags: linux, debian, amazon-ec2, fstab

I've been following [this tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/Howto_CREATE_BUNDLE_UPLOAD_and_ACCESS_custom_Debian_AMI_using_ubuntu) to create a custom amazon ec2 image. It looks like debootstrap doesn't set up the fstab anymore.

When I get to the `mount /proc` step, it complains:

```
warning: can't open /etc/mtab: No such file or directory
mount: can't find /proc in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

What do I need to do in order to configure the fstab for the first time? I have got a copy of the fstab on my local Linux Debian install but I don't know if there is some script/config command I have to run in order to configure the system. Also, do i need to create /etc/mtab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a plain text file, and you can open it in any text editor (e.g. vim, emacs, nano) to add entries to it. `/etc/mtab` is created on the fly, and you should not modify it.